# Perl regex matching problem

Tags: regex, perl

I think I'm missing something simple here...

```
$key = "deco-1-LB-700F:MAR:40";
  if ($key =~ m/deco-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)/) {
      print "1=$1 2=$2 3=$3 4=$4 5=$5";
  }
```

This results in the output: 1=1 2=LB 3=700F 4=MAR 5=

Why isn't $5 returning the value 40 ?

Cheers, Stu

Comment: Do you need tghe last ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `.*?` is lazy and will match zero characters if it can. Anchor the regex to the end of the string:

```
$key =~ m/deco-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)$/
```

But it's nearly always better to use something more explicit than the catch-all `.*` and `.*?`. Tell the regex engine exactly what you want to allow to match. Assuming that the delimiters `-` and `:` never occur in the actual matches, I suggest

```
$key =~ m/deco-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)$/
```

- `[^-]` means "match any character except `-`".
- `[^:]` means "match any character except `:`".

Comment: Thanks Tim, I had added the `$` to the end but for some reason my perl didn't like it and hung on me, now it's working ok :)

Comment: It may have hung because the string didn't match, and the number of permutations for all those `.*?` went exponential. This is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and it's one of the reasons why `.*` should be avoided if a more specific matching rule is possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
split qr/[:-]/, 'deco-1-LB-700F:MAR:40'
```

returns

```
(
    'deco',
    1,
    'LB',
    '700F',
    'MAR',
    40,
)
```

Comment: Came here to post that. Way simpler. Assuming you've actually got the string starting with `deco` by itself. The OP may be searching for it in a bigger body of text.

Comment: Thank you, that is way easier! And yes I am only searching strings starting with deco in that format. I must thank Tim though as he did answer my question why $5 was not what I expected but I will use this as the answer in my coding